# Adding y-offset for background image using n:th child in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have following code

```
<style>
    .first {
        width: 100%; 
        height: 600px; 
        margin:20px 0;
    }
</style>


<div class="first" 
     style="background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 100% 1800% transparent;">
</div>
<div class="first"  
     style="background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px -600px / 100% 1800% transparent;">
</div>
```

As you might have observed the only thing that is changing in background of these divs is y-offset. Is there any way I can set y-offset for n:th child at once? Is there anything else that can serve the same purpose?

Something like

```
div:nth-child(n) { 
    background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px -600px*n / 100% 1800% transparent; 
}
```

This will save a lot of time.

**UPDATE**

I don't have to put many images not just two.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<style>
.first {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 600px; 
    margin:20px 0;
    background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 100% 1800% transparent;
}
.last {
    background-position: 0px -600px;
}
</style>


 <div class="first">
 </div>
 <div class="first last">
 </div>
```

There are a few options available, but this is a pretty simple one for this issue.

If you really want to save time on your css, try using a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 nth-last-child(1). Also see the link for refrence.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/

```
.first {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 600px; 
    margin:20px 0;
    background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px / 100% 1800% transparent;
}
div.first:nth-last-child(1) {
    background: url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0px -600px / 100% 1800% transparent;
}
```